# Copy constructor invocation - return value

Tags: c++

Given the following very simple code :

```
class X{}

X something() {
      return X();
}
```

and:

```
X something() {
      X x;
      return x;
}
```

The 2nd example probably (Might have compiler optimizations) make 2 copies - first for the first line and second for the return value.
but what about the first one? does it make a copy 2 times? or only one?

thanks!

Comment: Both examples won't make any copies; they'll move `X`.

Comment: What if X has no move ctor?

Comment: There is nothing to move, but `X` does have a compiler generated move constructor. What may well happen is that *return value optimization* kicks in, eliding all copies.

Answer (score 1):

The two examples are the same, modern compiler should have implemented [Return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)